# Regex expression to remove only two first quotes in every line of text

Tags: regex

I need to remove only first two quotes in every line:

```
"key0": "some very long text",
"key1": "some very long text",
```

into

```
  key0: "some very long text",
  key1: "some very long text",
```

I tried `[^"]{2}` `"{2}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

**Find What**: `^([^"]*)"([^"]*)"`
Or, if there are lines with no quotes in them, so as to avoid overmatching:
**Find What**: `^([^"\r\n]*)"([^"\r\n]*)"`
**Replace With**: `$1$2`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJoh3k/1).

*Details*:

- `^` -  start of string
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more chars other than a `"` char (`[^"\r\n]*` matches any zero or more chars other than `"`, CR and LF)
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): zero or more chars other than a `"` char
- `"` - a `"` char